# Why is this Array.prototype.reduce method not working

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
function dropElements(arr, func) {
    let output = arr.reduce((acc=[], elem) => {
        if (func(elem)){
            acc.push(arr.slice(arr.indexOf(elem)))
            return acc
        }
    }, [])
    return output
}

let tester = dropElements([1, 2, 3, 4,5,6,3,2,1], function(n) {return n >= 3;})
console.log(tester)
```

I want it to output [3,4,5,6,3,2,1]. But is printing copies of size decreasing arrays.

The statement of the problem:  "Given the array arr, iterate through and remove each element starting from the first element (the 0 index) until the function func returns true when the iterated element is passed through it."

Comment: [MDN Array#slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#return_value)

Comment: why are you using this complicated `reduce`r instead of `let output = arr.filter(func)`;

Comment: This is the statement of the problem "Given the array arr, iterate through and remove each element starting from the first element (the 0 index) until the function func returns true when the iterated element is passed through it."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) along with [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to find the first index at which the callback function returns `true`.

```js
function dropElements(arr, func) {
  const idx = arr.findIndex(func);
  return idx >= 0 ? arr.slice(idx) : [];
}
console.log(dropElements([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 2, 1], n => n >= 3));
```

If you specifically want to use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), you could use a variable to store whether or not the callback has returned true for any element so far.

```js
function dropElements(arr, func) {
  let found = false;
  return arr.reduce((acc, elem) => {
    found = found || func(elem);
    if (found) acc.push(elem);
    return acc;
  }, []);
}
console.log(dropElements([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 2, 1], n => n >= 3));
```

Comment: I am using reduce because I was not asked to filter an array using a function. I should had posted the statement of the problem "Given the array arr, iterate through and remove each element starting from the first element (the 0 index) until the function func returns true when the iterated element is passed through it."

Comment: I like the solution. But is there a way to solve the problem using `reduce()`

Comment: @CharlesXavier You could `reduce` like so: https://jsfiddle.net/73ox84wh/

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) method to remove the first element from the array until the array is empty or `func(arr[0])` returns a truthy value. This method is inefficient as it could be, but it matches the problem statement. Particularly:

- It removes each element singularly, rather than all at once.
- It removes elements while iterating.
- It operates on the array itself, rather than a copy.

```js
function dropElements(arr, func) {
  while (arr.length > 0 && !func(arr[0])) {
    arr.shift();
  }
  return arr;
}

let tester = dropElements([1, 2, 3, 4,5,6,3,2,1], function(n) {return n >= 3;});
console.log(tester);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reduce does apply the function to all elements of the array, not just the first matching the function. Your reduce function as called will return an undefined value, if the function (n >= 3) does not return true for any element.

Thus using the fact array is non-empty when the result is found, the properly functioning reduce would be following:

```
function dropElements(arr, func) {
  return arr.reduce((acc, elem) => {
    // The more verboes would be acc.length > 0 || func(element)
    const found = acc.length || func(elem);
    if (found) acc.push(elem);
    return acc;
  }, []);
}

console.log(dropElements([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 2, 1], n => n >= 3));
```